# deploy:assets:precompile Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2, capistrano

I am trying to deploy a rails application to the rackspace server via capistrano. I have deployed many Rails application to Rackspace and Linode server and never encountered such weird issue. The capistrano is not deploying the application and below is the log :

```
executing `deploy:assets:precompile'
  * executing "cd /home/deployer/apps/latty39/releases/20121023165957 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile"
    servers: ["50.56.183.16"]
    [50.56.183.16] executing command
 ** [out :: 50.56.183.16] rake aborted!
 ** [out :: 50.56.183.16] cannot load such file -- Date
 ** [out :: 50.56.183.16] 
 ** [out :: 50.56.183.16] (See full trace by running task with --trace)
    command finished in 7454ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /home/deployer/apps/latty39/releases/20121023165957; true"
    servers: ["50.56.183.16"]
    [50.56.183.16] executing command
    command finished in 2001ms
failed: "sh -c 'cd /home/deployer/apps/latty39/releases/20121023165957 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile'" on 50.56.183.16
```

I have no idea why this is failing. I have almost spent 3 hours on this thing and no success so far. Have search stackoverflow and other resources but no help.

Any help to resolve the issue will be highly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: what does `--trace` output show

Comment: @Viren: actually nothing is displayed in trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself. I was having a custom rake task which was requiring ruby Date Class like:

```
require 'Date'
```

Removed it and all fixed. But I do not need to figure out why requiring the date class in production throws error.